# Python: getting variable from user function

Tags: python, function

im trying to make a simple text game for a school project and also make the code somewhat clean therefore I started using functions and classes.

The problem is im stuck on trying to access a variable from a function that asks the user for their username.

Here is my code

```
def playername():
    print("What is your name?")
    playername = input()
```

how can I access the playername variable without running the whole function again so once I run it at the start and get the username I can use that same input username later on in the code?

Comment: store it as a variable outside of function. for example `string playerName = playername()` and add `return playername` to the end of the function  "playername"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your function like this:

```
def get_playername():
    playername = input('Whats is your name? ')
    return playername
```

Then,use it:

```
name = get_playername()
```

Answer (score 0):

store it as a variable outside of function. for example string playerName = playername() and add return playername to the end of the function "playername"

```
def playername():
    print("What is your name?")
    playername = input()
    return playername

def main():
    playerName = playername()
    print(playerName)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's a good idea to name your function and variables differently. So, I'd use something like "name" to store the name of the player.

You can print the question and store the value at the same step with the input() function

```
def playername():
    name = input("Enter you name: ")
    print("Hello {}".format(name))
    return name

name = playername()
```

Answer (score 0):

playername variable is limited (scoped) to playername function, it cannot be accessed from outside the function

You should return the playername value, so that the function caller can store and use this value

```
def playername():
    print("What is your name?")
    playername = input()
    return playername

def main():
    my_playername = playername()
    # use my_playername as much as you like
    ...

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Returning values from a function is a basic programming skill.  I strongly recommend that you work through class materials or a tutorial on the topic.

```
def get_player_name():
    print("What is your name?")
    name = input()    # Do NOT give two program objects the same name.
    return name

# Main Program

victim_name = get_player_name()
```